# How to I enable mutual TLS in terraform for a custom domain with the intention of uploading the real certificate later?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, mtls

We are trying to enable mutual TLS on our API gateway custom domain using terraform.

```
mutual_tls_authentication = {
  truststore_uri     = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.truststore.bucket}/truststore.pem"
}
```

The file `truststore.pem` does not exist in the bucket yet as we plan to upload our certificate to the bucket later, but the terraform fails saying the URI is not valid (I interpret that to mean that it's looking for the physical file and the file does not exist).

> Error: Error creating API Gateway Domain Name: BadRequestException: Invalid truststore URI/versionId specified.

To get around this, I created a dummy `aws_s3_object` in the bucket called `truststore.pem` and re-ran the terraform, only to receive this error:

```
Error: Error creating API Gateway Domain Name: BadRequestException: Must have at least one certificate in truststore.
```

So I can go ahead and create an actual certificate in terraform and reference that but it just feels unnecessarily complicated that we can't add the mutual TLS to the `api_gateway_domain_name` until we have created the S3 bucket and added at least one valid certificate to the `truststore.pem file`.

Is this the correct approach (i.e. have to create dummy certificate to be replaced later) or am I missing something?

Comment: Why does it seem unnecessarily complicated that you can't enable mutual TLS without a TLS certificate? How would you expect it to work otherwise? What would mutual TLS without a TLS certificate look like? Perhaps you should simply add a flag in your Terraform code to disable mutual TLS until such time as you have a TLS certificate ready to install.

Comment: It does sound a bit silly when you put it like that. I think I expected a runtime error as opposed to a creation error. If we added a flag to disable mutual TPS for now, then when we do have the real certificate, the terraform still needs to run to create the bucket to add the certificate to and we still need to reference the file in the `truststore_uri`, so we still have the chicken and egg situation. Are you suggesting that the solution here is to create a dummy cert in terraform, reference it and then replace it manually with our real one? i.e. the thing I thought was a bit unnecessary.

Comment: No, I'm saying there is not a chicken and egg situation. If you have a parameter like `tls_certificate_file` in your Terraform code, you can have it check if that parameter is empty/null and use that as a decision. If not present it can simply not create the S3 bucket, S3 object, and not enable mTLS. If present, it can create the bucket, then upload the file to the bucket, then enable mTLS. You just run `terraform apply` now without specifying that parameter, and then when you have the certificate, run `terraform apply` again with the parameter.